# My Android app gets 'Javascript not enabled' message back from POST

Tags: javascript, java, php, android

I am writing an Android app that requires access to a MySql server.  Following examples I have found, I have a php page that sits on the server and does the MySql stuff, and I try to access that from my app.  I am using Android Studio, and running the app in the emulator.  I can successfully call the php from the emulator's browser (which has Javascript enabled), but when I try to call it from my app I get a page back that includes the message 'This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support'

My php code is as follows:

```php
<?php
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$con=mysqli_connect("mysqlserver.com",$username,$password,"mydatabase");

if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM table1 where name='$name'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$data = "$row[0] $row[1]";

if($data)
{
    echo $data;
}
else
{
    echo "No data returned";
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

My Java fragment is:

```java
try{
    String username = "user";
    String password = "password";
    String name = "name";

    // Set up connection
    String link="http://myserver.com/temp.php";
    String data  = URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8");
    data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");
    data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("name", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8");

    URL url = new URL(link);
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

    // POST to page
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
    OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(os);

    wr.write( data );
    wr.flush();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

    // Read Server Response
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;

    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        sb.append(line);
    }
    String strMessage = sb.toString();
    char[] message = strMessage.toCharArray();
    DialogFragment dialog = OKDialogFragment.newInstance(message);
    dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "OKDialogFragmentTag");
}
catch(Exception e){
    String strMessage = "Exception: " + e.getMessage();
    char[] message = strMessage.toCharArray();
    DialogFragment dialog = OKDialogFragment.newInstance(message);
    dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "OKDialogFragmentTag");
}
```

Is there any way I can tell my URLConnection to enable Javascript?  The server I am using is a hosting site (Byethost), just for testing.

Comment: Having no javascript interpreter you want to enable it? For what?

Comment: I have no need for Javascript, but the message I am getting seems to be telling me that the server won't process my php because the site requires my browser to have Javascript enabled.  I believe that a Webview has the option to enable JS, so presumably Android has access to a JS interpreter? I wasn't planning to use a Webview myself, as I have no interest in displaying the page that comes back.

Comment: Don't know how a browser tells the server thatis is capable of doing javascript. Sorry. But i suppose it puts that info in a header. So please google for that.

Comment: Thanks for your responses.  Possibly the message I am getting back is a red herring, and I have some error I can't find in my code.  In any case I have found a slightly different route (as I will detail in my answer below), which does work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the message I was getting may be a red herring, as I can get my data back correctly using a WebView whether Javascript is enabled or not.  I still don't know why my code didn't work (I tried both the deprecated apache.org.http.* and java.net.*, using the identical url to the one that works with WebView), but I can work an alternative solution using WebView, so that is what I will do.

Comment: Hi, Can you post some of your code or some helpful link from which you have returned the json from server using WebView